# How do I hide the English language from the language bar?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, english, language-bar

My operating system is in English.

I have two keyboards: Spanish and Japanese. I speak Spanish natively, and I'm learning Japanese, but to write in English I just use the Spanish keyboard.

The problem is that in the language bar I see three keyboard layouts, and so pressing Alt+Shift changes the languages between those three: Spanish, Japanese and English.

Is there any way to disable this? Or am I doomed because I use the OS in English?

Here is an image explaining the situation:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simply add it in Text services and input languages, apply the changes and then remove it again will make it disappear from the language bar.

Comment: I have same problem and this workaround doesn't solvet this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove English from the language bar, you need to do the following:

1. Open Control Panel and under the heading **Clock, Language, and Region**, select **Change keyboards or other input methods**.
2. On the **Keyboards and Languages** tab, click **Change keyboards...**.
3. On the **General** tab, select the language you wish to remove and click **Remove**.
4. (optional) If you want to change the keyboard shortcut used to swap between languages, you can do so by going to the **Advanced Key Settings** tab, changing the appropriate settings.

Comment: As I said I only have the Spanish and Japanese keyboards there, not the English keyboard, hence the problem, the English keyboard shows up in the language bar although I don't have it added as a default keyboard layout.

Comment: @Zequez Oh I see what you mean now.  Is English showing up as the default language in the dialog box even though the keyboard layout isn't there?  If so, is it possible to change it to Spanish in the dropdown list?  Edit: Here's an image of the options I'm talking about: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NSSEL.gif

Comment: No, what I mean is this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3682061/i_mean_this.png

Comment: Alright, can you try this for me?  Control Panel -> Clock, Language and Region, select **Install or uninstall display languages** and see if English is in the list.