# How to disable one keyboard language that case when don't see it in the language bar?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, language, language-bar

I have strange problem in my computer. I use two keyborad local: Hungary, English. After Windows Update my computer default language was set to Latvia (LV). But I cannot see this languauge in settings of my Windows. Here is detailed picture (Lett == Latvia, Angol == English, Magyar == Hungary):

[image]

You can see my default language is Hungary, but the Windows always set to Latvia after restart, logout etc.

How can I disable/delete LV keyboard local?

Comment: I'm curious. When you cycle languages by using Alt-Shift, does LV get selected eventually, or does Windows skip it (so it only cycles the languages that are showing in the settings window, not in the language bar) ?

Comment: Same problem: http://superuser.com/questions/363687/how-do-i-hide-the-english-language-from-the-language-bar?rq=1

Comment: Yes, same problem, but it doesn't solved my problem the answers of this question. How can I fix it?